# Android : Change color of drawable rectangle and ActionBar depending on layout file

Tags: java, android, orientation, landscape, portrait

I've been stuck for a while on something that sounds basic. I want to change the ActionBar and two drawable rectangles colors according to the orientation of the device using two layout files. I also have two activities.

Right now, I've coded this into a controller (calling the function in OnResume) :

```
public void changeColor(int orientation) {
    String className = context.getClass().getSimpleName();

    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if (className.equals("MainActivity")) {
            // Change actionbar, big square and small square colors
        }
        if (className.equals("WelcomeActivity")) {
            // Change actionbar color
        }
    } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        if (className.equals("MainActivity")) {
            // change actionbar, big square and small square colors
        } else if (className.equals("WelcomeActivity")) {
            // change actionbar color
        }
    }
}
```

It sounds like something that could be fixed using a layout for portrait and a layout for landscape to have different colors for both of them. Is this possible? Right now with this function, it sounds like I'm reinventing the wheel.

EDIT : My drawable shape (rectangle) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="25dp" />
    <solid android:color="#17D9C5" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide different resources depending on the orientation of the device. In your case, add a color resource file `res/values/colors.xml` for portrait as well as a file  `res/values-land/colors.xml` specifically for landscape.

Then, define colors *in both files* like so

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorRectangle1">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorRectangle2">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

and use different rgb values as desired.

Next, use the color resources in your `Activity` theme. You can set the theme for an `Activity` in the `Manifest.xml` and declare it in `res/values/styles.xml`. The color for the ActionBar is determined by

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

And, last not least, use the color resources in the drawable resource files:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="25dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorRectangle1" />
</shape>
```